# SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, certificate

SSL certificate is valid only for website without www

I set my site with SSL certificate.
It is on posidonia.ga
but if I connect then Firefox shows this warning:
""Websites guarantee their identity through certificates. Firefox does not consider this site reliable as it uses a certificate that is not valid for www.posidonia.ga. The certificate is valid only for posidonia.ga.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN""

So how could I connect to https://www.posidonia.ga if my SSL certificate is valid only for posidonia.ga (without www)?

I've read I could solve adding these lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the problem is still there.

Please help, thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I expect connecting https://www.posidonia.ga without
warning:
SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1) your certificate is only for `posidonia.ga` hence it will never cover `www.posidonia.ga` and any HTTPS connection to that hostname with this certificate will get rejected by clients due to name mismatch. You need a new certificate having either `www.posidonia.ga` or `*.posidonia.ga` as a SAN (Subject Alternative Name), alongside the current `posidonia.ga`. You need to generate a new certificate for this goal, you can not just "update" the current one.

2) Your certificate is issued by

```
E = support@cacert.org
CN = CA Cert Signing Authority
OU = http://www.cacert.org
O = Root CA
```

This is a CA that is not included by default in browsers (see http://wiki.cacert.org/InclusionStatus for full list on where it is included by default or not), hence they reject your certificate as unknown issuer.

To add the CA in browsers, have a look at http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/ImportRootCert and http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/BrowserClients depending on your needs.

It can be as simple as http://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3 and accepting the prompts, or more complicated depending on your OS/browser/setup/policies.

Comment: I understand that CAcert is not included in most browser. So which Signing Authority should I use? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use another SSL certificate with both posidonia.ga and www.posidonia.ga (using https://zerossl.com/free-ssl) but the ownership verification failed and I have no access to DNS txt editing. Thanks.

Comment: No, @passegua, right now you still get "Unknown issuer" because CAcert is not by default in browsers. It could work with you, but other people accessing your website will have an error (depending on what they have in their truststore). It is up to you to decide if that is a risk you want to take and/or educate your users. Otherwise there are plenty for free or not for free CAs around the world. The major player in the "certificate for free and root in browser" segment is Let's Encrypt, but it is just one possible choice.

Comment: Thanks your comment I eventually succeeded in verifying my site using https://www.sslforfree.com that create a free Let's Encrypt certificate. Please check your self if https://www.posidonia.ga is secure.

Comment: Some online services will test things for you and provide plethora of useful information: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or https://tls.imirhil.fr/ for example